# How to connect via websocket?

Tags: python, api, websocket

I have such part of code(Python):

```
def func_login_params():        
   async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
   # login
   timestamp = str(get_local_timestamp())
   login_str = login_params(timestamp, api_key, passphrase, secret_key)
   await ws.send(login_str)
   res = await ws.recv()
    
   # params
   sub_str = json.dumps(params)
   await ws.send(sub_str)
```

Upper code works - okey. But **I need to have two function: first - login, second - send params. As I thought I could do this:**

```
def func_login():
   async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
   # login
   timestamp = str(get_local_timestamp())
   login_str = login_params(timestamp, api_key, passphrase, secret_key)
   await ws.send(login_str)
   res = await ws.recv()
def func_params():
   async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
   # params
   sub_str = json.dumps(params)
   await ws.send(sub_str)
```

But in this situation params don't come. Maybe it don't connect correctly?

Comment: Okay, but let me clarify maybe it's important, so it's code from the SDK, the second is that with this api I make a position on the site. So I do not know for sure maybe just the data does not processed correctly but the lower code is not exactly the same as the top.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to connect websockets, it creates new connection.
So, in that case, you should take an websocket connection as function argument:

```
async def func_login(ws):
    timestamp = str(get_local_timestamp())
    login_str = login_params(timestamp, api_key, passphrase, secret_key)
    await ws.send(login_str)
    res = await ws.recv()

async def func_params(ws):
    sub_str = json.dumps(params)
    await ws.send(sub_str)

def main():
    async with web sockets.connect(url) as ws:
        await func_login(ws)
        await func_params(ws)
```

Comment: Thx, but I need to login in one place of code, then after some time, in other function call func_params(it won't be in the same "async with web sockets.connect(url) as ws:"). So maybe webosckets.connect() don't fit(as you wrote about additional connection).